# SQL Server : how do I return only rows that match 2 field when the 3rd is different

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter

I have the following table

```
Fruit          Color      Type
------------------------------
Apple          Red          1 
Apple          Red          4 
Apple          Green        1 
Apple          Yellow       1 
Grape          Red          1 
Grape          Green        4 
Grape          Green        1 
Grape          Purple       1 
Grape          Yellow       1
```

- Grape          Green        2
- Apple          Red          2

I want to return this because there a repeat of Fruit and Color but different Types

```
Fruit         Color 
---------------------
Apple         Red 
Grape         Green
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE: I apologize for my lack of clarity. There are other Types that I did not include. I've updated the table with a star next to the newly added lines to reflect my ignorance. I only want to get types 1 & 4, not 2 or any other type number.

Comment: If you only want to consider lines with types 1 and 4, then you would simply add a where clause to the answer provided by Joe Coehoorn: `WHERE type IN (1,4)`. This filter is evaluated before the group-by and having clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a `HAVING` filter.

```
SELECT fruit, color
FROM [table]
WHERE type IN (1,4)
GROUP BY fruit, color
HAVING count(distinct type) > 1
```

Comment: A handy script to sure. Unfortunately it doesn't do want I need. I've updated above that there are more types than necessary and this script finds all fruits & colors that are entered more than once but doesn't list types 1 & 4. thank you though for sure.

Comment: @S95 Updated based on your comment

Comment: Not sure what you meant with `count(type)` but it was probably `count(distinct type)`. As it stands, this code is the same as `count(*)` for a non-null column, and the same as `count(case when type is not null then 1 end)` for nullable columns

Comment: Correct. I forgot the distinct :( Fixing.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I was even able to add more where clauses. The only issue is that I wanted to include an ID column, but since it is unique, there are no results. But it works fine. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

By Using **ROW NUMBER**

```
SELECT * INTO #T FROM (VALUES('Apple','Red',1),
('Apple','Red',4),
('Apple','Green',1),
('Apple','Yellow',1),
('Grape','Red',1),
('Grape','Green',4),
('Grape','Green',1),
('Grape','Purple',1),
('Grape','Yellow',1)) AS S(Fruit,Color,Type)


SELECT S.Fruit,S.Color FROM (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (Partition BY Fruit,Color ORDER BY Fruit) AS RN  FROM #T) S 
WHERE S.RN>1
```

Expected Result:

```
Fruit   Color
Apple   Red
Grape   Green
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a subquery cross apply

```
declare @T as table(Fruit  varchar(10), Color varchar(10), Type int);

insert into @T 
VALUES('Apple','Red',1),
('Apple','Red',4),
('Apple','Green',1),
('Apple','Yellow',1),
('Grape','Red',1),
('Grape','Green',4),
('Grape','Green',1),
('Grape','Purple',1),
('Grape','Yellow',1)

select * from @T a
cross apply
(
  select Fruit, Color from @T b
  where a.Fruit=b.Fruit and a.Color=b.Color and b.Type>a.Type
)b

output:
Apple  Red    1  Apple  Red
Grape  Green  1  Grape  Green
```